# problem with niginx: nginx[14701]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: firefox, php, nginx

I am trying to install ph8. I had earlier php7.4 running under nginx. When I executed following command:

@lc2530hz:`~$ journalctl -xe`

```
Jun 04 16:46:22 lc2530hz nginx[14701]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address alre
Jun 04 16:46:22 lc2530hz rtkit-daemon[3488]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jun 04 16:46:22 lc2530hz rtkit-daemon[3488]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
```

Then I tried the following command:

```
$     sudo netstat -plant | grep 80

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1953/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.146:44802     151.101.192.233:443     ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.146:53902     72.21.91.29:80          ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.146:38040     44.239.205.250:443      ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.146:48782     151.101.180.157:443     ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.146:37252     13.249.79.210:80        ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1953/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:48006 2600:1901:0:e988:::443  ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:56636 2607:f8b0:4000:800::443 ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:36172 2600:1404:cc00:3::17:80 ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:51358 2607:f8b0:4000:80b::443 ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:39800 2606:4700::6810:f8f:443 ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:38298 2607:f8b0:4000:80b:::80 ESTABLISHED 5957/firefox        
tcp6       0      0 2600:1700:e040:79:55804 2a04:4e42:400::396:443
```

Somebody please guide me how to solve this problem.

Zulfi.

==Updated Jun8, 2022

@waltinator Hi, I am getting the same answer as above i.e. firsfox and nginx are sharing port 80.

```
nginx    2146 www-data    6u  IPv4  37535      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    2146 www-data    7u  IPv6  37536      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    2147 www-data    6u  IPv4  37535      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    2147 www-data    7u  IPv6  37536      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
firefox 24166    zulfi  118u  IPv4 251955      0t0  TCP lc2530hz.attlocal.net:44274->server-108-138-165-98.dfw56.r.cloudfront.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 24166    zulfi  157u  IPv6 251982      0t0  TCP lc2530hz.attlocal.net:60494->rw-in-f94.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 24166    zulfi  161u  IPv6 251978      0t0  TCP lc2530hz.attlocal.net:60486->rw-in-f94.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: You can see which process has port 80 open with `sudo lsof -i tcp:80`

Comment: @waltinator I am already determining that using netsta -plant, please guide me how to make sure that firefox uses different port